# Android Saving data to MySQL

Tags: java, android, database

I am creating an app that requires a login page in android studios. I have already created the database and linked it to the app fine but do not know how to save the values of text boxes to the database using a button. Below is my code for the database and all:

```
package com.example.register;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import java.sql.*;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.example.ben.restaurantapp.R;

import java.sql.Connection;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
}

private Connection getConnection()
{

    String host = "jdbc:mysql://jdbc.fmc.me.uk:3306/db_ben";
    String u = "user_ben";
    String p = "******";
    try
    {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, u, p);
        return con;
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private boolean registerUser(){

    //Get username
    EditText regUsernameBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegUsername);
    String regUsernameStr = regUsernameBox.getText().toString();

    //Get password
    EditText regPasswordBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegPassword);
    String regPasswordStr = regPasswordBox.getText().toString();

    System.out.println(regUsernameStr);
    System.out.println(regPasswordStr);

    return false;
}

public void buttonClick() {
    final Button registerUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

    registerUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerUser();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Use the connection to insert data, maybe?

Comment: No i dont know the code to do it. I was wondering if anyone could help

Comment: Writing directly to MySQL from an Android app isn't a good idea. I would also advise you to change your password, assuming the one in the code above is yours. Without showing what you've tried, after having done some initial research into how to save data to MySQL from Java, you aren't likely to get much help.

Answer (score 0):

You can transition Java object to json string, send to server.
like this:

```
//findViewById();
String regUsernameStr = regUsernameBox.getText().toString();
String regPasswordStr = regPasswordBox.getText().toString();
User user = new User();
user.setName(regUsernameStr);
user.setPassword(regPasswordStr);
String json = new Gson().toJson(user);
//network regist code...
```

Answer (score 0):

Call buttonClick() in **onCreate()** method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    buttonClick();
    }
```

But this code never works because you never call getConnection()